# Facilitating sentence diagramming?

Tags: feature-request

Having had many discussions on other forums that essentially turned on trying to express an opinion about the tree structure of a sentence, are there any clever ways to illustrate a sentence diagram on this site?

[[[I'm] aware] [of [[this sort] [of diagramming.]]]]

But it isn't all that readable and is tricky to visually compare with

[[[I'm] aware] [[of [this sort]] [of diagramming.]]]]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [tools for diagramming](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1024/tools-for-parsing-diagramming). An example is at [help me diagram this sentence](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21978/can-someone-help-me-diagram-this-sentence):

[image: parse tree of the sentence]

The image was created by using

- [phpSyntaxTree](http://lrv.bplaced.net/syntaxtree/?)

with the input:

- [S [AdvP [ADV no matter the season]] [NP [DET these] [ADJ combined] [N features] ] [VP [V present] [NP [ART a]  [AdjP [ADV uniquely] [AdjP [Adj varied] and [Adj demanding]]] challenge [AdjP found [AdvP nowhere else ]]]]]

which I created out of thin air.

Comment: I had been using [this version](http://www.ironcreek.net/phpsyntaxtree/?) of phpSyntxTree, but I am overjoyed to see that your version supports unicode. :)  This is the sort of thing that should go into the faq!  Though I'm sure there are enough folks who enjoy tree drawing enough to edit it in for others.

Comment: This is amazing. Please, put it into the FAQ! Maybe even offer direct integration into the site at some point.

Comment: @JSBᾶngs: I was secretly thinking that, but I didn't know how readily SE staff would add something that only a few people would utilize.  (Come to think of it, I don't know anything about the process for site upgrades.)